# Apply conditional function in every row of a data frame

Tags: r

I'm new in R and I'm struggling with this df that looks like this:

```
Date      Group       Factor 1 Factor 2 Spread
2019-04-01  a   1.01    1.011   0.01
2019-04-02  a   1.02    1.012   0.02
2019-04-03  a   1.03    1.013   0.03
2019-04-01  b   1.005   1.004   0.01
2019-04-02  b   1.0051  1.0041  0.02
2019-04-03  b   1.0052  1.0042  0.03
```

I would like do verify each group in each row and if the results are Group "a" do Factor1/Factor1(1 day lag) * Factor2 + spread, and if the group it's not "a" do not add the spread.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What happens with the lag when you're looking at the first row of the group? Is the value of `spread` for group `"b"` supposed to be `NA`? (Questions with code you've already tried are often accepted better with more appropriately-geared suggestions/answers.)

Comment: I have tried:

if(df$Group == "a"){
 df%>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(NewCol = (Factor1/dplyr::lag(Factor1, n =1 , default = NA)*Factor2 + spread)
}
else{
df%>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(NewCol = (Factor1/dplyr::lag(Factor1, n =1 , default = NA)*Factor2} 
}

Comment: In general, code does not format well in comments. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55800579/edit) the question and add it into a code-block in there.

Comment: ... but the problem with that code is that your first conditional `(df$Group == "a")` should be a single logical, but in this case it is returning a vector of logicals, not what `if` will handle. I think my answer addresses what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are conditioning on the group, this is a good example of `by` (base R), `dplyr::group_by`, or `data.table`'s `x[,,by=]`.

The equation is effectively the same in all three, capitalizing on the fact that `(Group[1] == "a")` will be coerced from a `logical` to `numeric` when multipled by a number; since `FALSE` translates to a 0, then effectively disabled adding `Spread`.

## Base

I use `within` here to make the internals a little more readable, but this is not a requirement (in which case you'd need to prepend `x$` in front of all of the variable names).

The lagging can be done using `dplyr::lag` (even if you don't use the rest of the package for this) or many other techniques. I don't find `stats::lag` to be the most intuitive in applications like this, but I'm sure somebody will suggest a way to incorporate it into an answer. The use of `c(NA, ...)` ensures that we don't bring in a different group's data or impute data we don't have, since we have no value to bring in on the first row of a group. Finally, `head(..., n = 1)` returns the first element of a vector/list, while `head(..., n = -1)` (negative) returns *all but the last*.

```r
newx <- by(x, x$Group, function(y) {
  within(y, {
    NewVal = Factor2 * Factor1 / c(NA, head(Factor1, n=-1)) + (Group[1] == "a") * Spread
  })
})
newx
# x$Group: a
#         Date Group Factor1 Factor2 Spread   NewVal
# 1 2019-04-01     a    1.01   1.011   0.01       NA
# 2 2019-04-02     a    1.02   1.012   0.02 1.042020
# 3 2019-04-03     a    1.03   1.013   0.03 1.052931
# -------------------------------------------------------
# x$Group: b
#         Date Group Factor1 Factor2 Spread NewVal
# 4 2019-04-01     b  1.0050  1.0040   0.01     NA
# 5 2019-04-02     b  1.0051  1.0041   0.02 1.0042
# 6 2019-04-03     b  1.0052  1.0042   0.03 1.0043
```

This is really just a `list` with some fancy `by`-specific formatting, so you can treat it as such as combine them in an efficient base-R way:

```r
do.call("rbind.data.frame", c(newx, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
#           Date Group Factor1 Factor2 Spread   NewVal
# a.1 2019-04-01     a  1.0100  1.0110   0.01       NA
# a.2 2019-04-02     a  1.0200  1.0120   0.02 1.042020
# a.3 2019-04-03     a  1.0300  1.0130   0.03 1.052931
# b.4 2019-04-01     b  1.0050  1.0040   0.01       NA
# b.5 2019-04-02     b  1.0051  1.0041   0.02 1.004200
# b.6 2019-04-03     b  1.0052  1.0042   0.03 1.004300
```

## `dplyr`

Many find the `tidyverse` line of packages to read intuitively.

```r
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(NewVal = Factor2 * Factor1 / lag(Factor1) + (Group[1] == "a") * Spread) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   Date       Group Factor1 Factor2 Spread NewVal
#   <chr>      <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 2019-04-01 a        1.01    1.01   0.01  NA   
# 2 2019-04-02 a        1.02    1.01   0.02   1.04
# 3 2019-04-03 a        1.03    1.01   0.03   1.05
# 4 2019-04-01 b        1.00    1.00   0.01  NA   
# 5 2019-04-02 b        1.01    1.00   0.02   1.00
# 6 2019-04-03 b        1.01    1.00   0.03   1.00
```

## `data.table`

On a different note, many find `data.table` better because of efficiencies gained from in-place modification (most of R's operations are copy-on-write, meaning some operations re-copy the object or a portion of it with each change).

```0r
library(data.table)
X <- as.data.table(x)
X[, NewVal := Factor2 * Factor1 / shift(Factor1) + (Group[1] == "a") * Spread, by = "Group"]
X
#          Date Group Factor1 Factor2 Spread   NewVal
# 1: 2019-04-01     a  1.0100  1.0110   0.01       NA
# 2: 2019-04-02     a  1.0200  1.0120   0.02 1.042020
# 3: 2019-04-03     a  1.0300  1.0130   0.03 1.052931
# 4: 2019-04-01     b  1.0050  1.0040   0.01       NA
# 5: 2019-04-02     b  1.0051  1.0041   0.02 1.004200
# 6: 2019-04-03     b  1.0052  1.0042   0.03 1.004300
```

The "in-place" part is evident on the second line here, where it appears as if the `[` operation should just return a subset or something of the data ... but in this case using `:=` causes the columns to be created (or changed) in-place.